# Issues installing Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Stuck on linux-signed-image-4.13.0.37-generic (amd64))

Tags: system-installation

Hello and thank you for your attention and help beforehand!

I've decided to install Ubuntu on my notebook, a Lenovo Ideapad 320, to run alongside Windows 10, but I'm facing some issues installing the system from my usb drive. Whenever I opt to install it, either straight from the BIOS or within the "try with installing" feature, the process seems to get stuck while "configuring linux-signed-image-4.13.0.37-generic (amd64)", with the installation logs repeatedly mentioning "Warning: Source ID #### was not found when attempting to remove it" with different increasing IDs every now and then.
I already left the process ongoing over night, but it seems to have made no difference.

I can provide any additional information if needed, but right now I wonder if anyone has any clue of what this might be.